# Can't configure websocketpp example CMakeLists.txt file

Tags: c++, websocket, cmake

When trying to configure the CMakeLists.txt file in the `examples/echo_server` folder in the [websocketpp](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp) repository from the CMake GUI on Windows 10, I get the following result:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (init_target):
  Unknown CMake command "init_target".


CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/examples/echo_server/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Why do I get the error `Unknown CMake command "init_target"`, and what do I do about it? I have googled it, but I only get one hit on that exact message and it is about building websocketpp, not an individual example.

Comment: Warning `No cmake_minimum_required command is present.` usually means that you run `cmake` from the directory, which is not prepared for that. `CMakeLists.txt` contained under `examples/<example-name>` directories are **not standalone**: For build examples you need to build the top level project (and set `BUILD_EXAMPLES` option to `ON`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Okay, thanks. Building the top level project with `BUILD_EXAMPLES` enabled gives me [linker errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54829251/link-errors-when-building-websocketpp-with-examples), though.

Answer (score 0):

`init_target` is not a cmake command.
It's a custom marco which is defined in `cmake/CMakeHelpers.cmake` file.

You should include it via `include(CMakeHelpers)` into your `CMakeLists.txt` to use `init_target` and other custom command.

Comment: It's not my `CMakeLists.txt`; it's the `CMakeLists.txt` in the example subfolder in the library's repository. If the `cmake/CMakeHelpers.cmake` should be included in it, shouldn't that already be the case in the repository (otherwise, I guess, this is a bug in their `CMakeLists.txt` file)?