# Link errors when building websocketpp with examples

Tags: c++, websocket, cmake, linker-errors

I'm having problems building [websocketpp](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp) with examples on Windows 10.

Here is what I do:

I first open the CMake GUI, and specify "D:/third-party-software/websocketpp" (which is the directory to which I have cloned websocketpp) as the location of the source code and "D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/build" as the place to build the binaries.

Then I press the button *Configure*, which asks me if I want to create the build folder, which I choose to do, and then which generator I want to use for the project, any optional toolset to use (argument to `-T`), and which compiler to use, for which I choose "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64", no optional toolset (empty string), and "use default native compiler", respectively.

Then I set the following parameters:

- `BUILD_EXAMPLES`: <enabled>
- `BOOST_ROOT`: "C:/Program1/boost/boost_1_67_0"
- `Boost_<LIBRARY-NAME>_LIBRARY_DEBUG` and
  `BOOST_<LIBRARY-NAME>_LIBRARY_RELEASE`:
  "C:/Program1/boost/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.1/boost_<library-name>-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_67.lib" and
  "C:/Program1/boost/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.1/boost_<library-name>-vc141-mt-x64-1_67.lib",
  respectively, for the libraries atomic, chrono, date_time, random, system and thread
- `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR`: "C:/Program1/boost/boost_1_67_0/"
- `Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG` and `Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE`: "C:/Program1/boost/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.1"

(I leave `Boost_DIR` uninitialized)

Then I press *Configure* again, which gives the output

```
* Configuring Boost
-- Using BOOST_ROOT
       C:/Program1/boost/boost_1_67_0
-- Include Directories
       C:/Program1/boost/boost_1_67_0/
-- Library Directories
       C:/Program1/boost/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.1
-- Libraries
       optimized
       C:/Program1/boost/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.1/boost_system-vc141-mt-x64-1_67.lib
       debug
       C:/Program1/boost/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.1/boost_system-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_67.lib
       optimized
       C:/Program1/boost/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.1/boost_thread-vc141-mt-x64-1_67.lib
       debug
       C:/Program1/boost/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.1/boost_thread-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_67.lib
       optimized
       C:/Program1/boost/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.1/boost_random-vc141-mt-x64-1_67.lib
       debug
       C:/Program1/boost/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.1/boost_random-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_67.lib
       optimized
       C:/Program1/boost/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.1/boost_chrono-vc141-mt-x64-1_67.lib
       debug
       C:/Program1/boost/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.1/boost_chrono-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_67.lib
       optimized
       C:/Program1/boost/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.1/boost_date_time-vc141-mt-x64-1_67.lib
       debug
       C:/Program1/boost/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.1/boost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_67.lib
       optimized
       C:/Program1/boost/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.1/boost_atomic-vc141-mt-x64-1_67.lib
       debug
       C:/Program1/boost/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.1/boost_atomic-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_67.lib

** websocketpp
** associative_storage
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** broadcast_server
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** debug_client
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** debug_server
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** echo_client
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** echo_server
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** echo_server_both
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** echo_server_tls
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** enriched_storage
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** external_io_service
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** handler_switch
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** iostream_server
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** print_client
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** print_client_tls
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** print_server
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** simple_broadcast_server
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** sip_client
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** subprotocol_server
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** telemetry_client
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** telemetry_server
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** testee_client
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** testee_server
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE
** utility_client
-- Build Type:
       EXECUTABLE

=========== Used Build Configuration =============

ENABLE_CPP11        = ON
BUILD_EXAMPLES      = ON
BUILD_TESTS         = OFF

WEBSOCKETPP_ROOT    = D:/third-party-software/websocketpp
WEBSOCKETPP_BIN     = D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/build/bin
WEBSOCKETPP_LIB     = D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/build/lib
Install prefix      = D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install

WEBSOCKETPP_BOOST_LIBS        = system;thread;random
WEBSOCKETPP_PLATFORM_LIBS     = 
WEBSOCKETPP_PLATFORM_TLS_LIBS = 

OPENSSL_FOUND        = TRUE
OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR     = C:/Program1/GDAL/release-1911-x64-dev/release-1911-x64/include
OPENSSL_LIBRARIES = C:/Program1/GDAL/release-1911-x64-dev/release-1911-x64/lib/ssleay32.lib;C:/Program1/GDAL/release-1911-x64-dev/release-1911-x64/lib/libeay32.lib
OPENSSL_VERSION = 1.0.1h

Configuring done
```

I the press *Generate*, which creates the Visual Studio solution, and *Open Project*, which opens the solution in Visual Studio 2017.

(I don't know what commands pressing each of these buttons would correspond to in the terminal.)

In Visual Studio, I right-click on the target *INSTALL* and click *Build*, and do that twice (to get rid of a lot of superfluous output). This results in the following output the second time I do it:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Release x64 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: debug_server, Configuration: Release x64 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: iostream_server, Configuration: Release x64 ------
4>------ Build started: Project: print_client_tls, Configuration: Release x64 ------
2>cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/arch:SSE2'
2>debug_server.cpp
4>cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/arch:SSE2'
4>print_client_tls.cpp
3>iostream_server.obj : MSIL .netmodule or module compiled with /GL found; restarting link with /LTCG; add /LTCG to the link command line to improve linker performance
3>iostream_server.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_htons
3>iostream_server.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_htonl
3>iostream_server.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_ntohs
3>D:\third-party-software\websocketpp\build\bin\Release\iostream_server.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
3>Done building project "iostream_server.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
2>D:\third-party-software\websocketpp\websocketpp/frame.hpp(834): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'uint32_t', possible loss of data
4>D:\third-party-software\websocketpp\websocketpp/frame.hpp(834): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'uint32_t', possible loss of data
2>D:\third-party-software\websocketpp\websocketpp/logger/syslog.hpp(34): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'syslog.h': No such file or directory
4>D:\third-party-software\websocketpp\websocketpp/common/md5.hpp(367): warning C4267: '+=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'websocketpp::md5::md5_word_t', possible loss of data
4>D:\third-party-software\websocketpp\websocketpp/sha1/sha1.hpp(176): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
4>D:\third-party-software\websocketpp\examples\print_client_tls\print_client_tls.cpp(71): error C3861: 'strcasecmp': identifier not found
4>D:\third-party-software\websocketpp\examples\print_client_tls\print_client_tls.cpp(106): error C3861: 'strcasecmp': identifier not found
2>Done building project "debug_server.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
4>Done building project "print_client_tls.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
5>------ Build started: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Release x64 ------
6>------ Build started: Project: INSTALL, Configuration: Release x64 ------
6>-- Install configuration: "Release"
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/cmake/websocketpp-config.cmake
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/cmake/websocketpp-configVersion.cmake
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/base64
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/base64/base64.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/client.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/close.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/common
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/common/asio.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/common/asio_ssl.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/common/chrono.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/common/connection_hdl.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/common/cpp11.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/common/functional.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/common/md5.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/common/memory.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/common/network.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/common/platforms.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/common/random.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/common/regex.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/common/stdint.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/common/system_error.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/common/thread.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/common/time.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/common/type_traits.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/concurrency
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/concurrency/basic.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/concurrency/none.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/config
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/config/asio.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/config/asio_client.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls_client.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/config/boost_config.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/config/core.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/config/core_client.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/config/debug.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/config/debug_asio.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/config/debug_asio_no_tls.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/config/minimal_client.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/config/minimal_server.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/connection.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/connection_base.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/endpoint.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/endpoint_base.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/error.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/extensions
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/extensions/extension.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/extensions/permessage_deflate
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/extensions/permessage_deflate/disabled.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/extensions/permessage_deflate/enabled.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/frame.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/http
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/http/constants.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/http/impl
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/http/impl/parser.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/http/impl/request.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/http/impl/response.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/http/parser.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/http/request.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/http/response.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/impl
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/impl/connection_impl.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/impl/endpoint_impl.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/impl/utilities_impl.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/logger
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/logger/basic.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/logger/levels.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/logger/stub.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/logger/syslog.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/message_buffer
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/message_buffer/alloc.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/message_buffer/message.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/message_buffer/pool.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/processors
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/processors/base.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/processors/hybi00.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/processors/hybi07.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/processors/hybi08.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/processors/hybi13.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/processors/processor.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/random
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/random/none.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/random/random_device.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/roles
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/roles/client_endpoint.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/roles/server_endpoint.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/server.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/sha1
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/sha1/sha1.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/asio
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/asio/base.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/asio/connection.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/asio/endpoint.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/asio/security
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/asio/security/base.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/asio/security/none.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/asio/security/tls.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/base
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/base/connection.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/base/endpoint.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/debug
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/debug/base.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/debug/connection.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/debug/endpoint.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/iostream
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/iostream/base.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/iostream/connection.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/iostream/endpoint.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/stub
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/stub/base.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/stub/connection.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/transport/stub/endpoint.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/uri.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/utf8_validator.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/utilities.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/include//websocketpp/version.hpp
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/bin/associative_storage.exe
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/bin/broadcast_server.exe
6>-- Up-to-date: D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/install/bin/debug_client.exe
6>CMake Error at examples/debug_server/cmake_install.cmake:37 (file):
6>  file INSTALL cannot find
6>  "D:/third-party-software/websocketpp/build/bin/Release/debug_server.exe".
6>Call Stack (most recent call first):
6>  cmake_install.cmake:56 (include)
6>
6>
6>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
6>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake
6>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
6>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd
6>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
6>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel
6>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1
6>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone
6>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
6>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(133,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.
6>Done building project "INSTALL.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 4 failed, 20 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

It seems like the linker is looking for the symbols `__imp_htons`, `__imp_htonl` and `__imp_ntohs` but cannot find them. How do I fix this?

Comment: Looks to me like ws2_32.lib is missing on the target_link_libraries call.

Comment: @vre So there is a bug in the build files in the repository, then? The only file that makes calls to `target_link_libraries` is [`cmake/CMakeHelpers.cmake`](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/master/cmake/CMakeHelpers.cmake). Do you know in which of the calls I should add `ws2_32.lib`?

Comment: After having a closer look onto the project I suppose your call to CMake is wrong. Can you addd the exact command you are using and from wich directory you are calling CMake?

Comment: I am asking because the output you showed does not include any build output from websocketpp but only from the examples directory.

Comment: @vre I've described more carefully what I've done. See my updated question.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Boost 1.67 it comes with WebSockets already, you don't need websocketpp:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/beast/doc/html/index.html

Comment: Interesting. So Boost's WebSocket is the Beast of the beast, if you get my drift.

Answer (score 1):

As it is too much for a comment I put it as an answer here.

You downloaded the project and extracted it from zip. Say to directory `D:\third-party-software\websocketpp`.

Remove any build artifacts before trying the following recipe, i.e. delete the build folder.

Open a console window. From the command line change to the parent directory

```
cd D:\third-party-software\websocketpp
cmake -H. -Bbuild -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -DBOOST_ROOT=C:/Program1/boost/boost_1_67_0
cmake --build build --target ALL_BUILD --config Release
```

That should build the entire project out of the box including the examples. If you rather like to work with Visual Studio you can easily open the generated solution file `*.sln` that is generated to the build folder.

This should build websocketpp first and then the examples. If that does not happen it's a problem with websocketpp, but I really don't think that.

Comment: I still get the same errors. The compilation errors are cause by attempted usage of POSIX-specific functionality, which doesn't exist natively in Windows, and can be resolved by removing or replacing the culprits. The linker errors persist, though.

Comment: By the way, why do you use the `-H` option? It is used to print the help. Did you intend to use `-S`?

Comment: -H was the old undocumented option for the source directory.  I'll have a closer look over next weekend as I do not have a computer right now available.

Comment: Ok, just downloaded and compiled websocketpp. It is broken for linking the examples. You need to add `set (WEBSOCKETPP_PLATFORM_LIBS ws2_32)` in line 115 in the top level CMakeLists.txt. Then all examples are linked with the winsocks2 library and the linker errors will disappear. I'll file a bug report and the proper fix on the project.